# How to start launch configuration after finishing another launch programmatically? (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So I need to start an launch config. depending on output from another launch configuration.

```java
Launch launch = (Launch) configurations[0].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE,
                            console);
                    do {
                        if(launch.isTerminated()){
                            configurations[1].launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE,
                                    new NullProgressMonitor());
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (!launch.isTerminated());
```

Something like this, but even this is not working. It executes only first launch. And how can I acces the output(from console) of first launch?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single question.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the answer. So there is a way to get console output from launch instance?

Comment: Ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get notified about the process associated with a launch terminating by using an `IDebugEventSetListener` listener.

Add the listener with:

```java
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```

When the process associated with the launch (if there is one) terminate a  `DebugEvent` will be passed to the listener's `handleDebugEvents` method.

The event `getKind()` method will return `DebugEvent.TERMINATE` for a terminated process. The event `getSource()` returns the `IProcess` which terminated.